# How do I get a string value from its hex in PostgreSQL?

Tags: string, postgresql, hex

I have a string value of `'2.4.3369.6'`. Using the command:
`select encode('2.4.3369.6', 'hex') as string_to_hex`

I translate this value into a hex and get the next value of

```
'322e342e333336392e36'
```

Which command or commands do I use to get the value `'2.4.3369.6'` from the value `'322e342e333336392e36'`?

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, `decode('322e342e333336392e36','hex')` doesn't work.

Comment: Everything works, thank you. Just my editor (pgadmin) why that values were not displayed!

Comment: `select '2.4.3369.6' as string_in_dec, encode('2.4.3369.6', 'hex') as string_to_hex, convert_from(decode('322e342e333336392e36','hex'),'UTF-8') as string_to_dec;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the encoding is `UTF8`, you could use the following to get it as `text`:

```
SELECT convert_from(decode('322e342e333336392e36','hex'), 'UTF8');

┌──────────────┐
│ convert_from │
├──────────────┤
│ 2.4.3369.6   │
└──────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Is there a postgres 12 compatible function for this ? I have scoured through the docs to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: @YY That works fine in v12, I just tried.